# Perl regexp to find an element inside an element

Tags: regex, perl

I need to find through regular expression from `<div id="class1">` to end of `</div>`. I may also have as many `<div>` within its text inside it. Please find the code below

```
This is example <div id="class1">This is <div id="subclass1">This is </div> <div id="subclass2">This is </div> This is </div> This is example
```

I have tried the below code. But it gets only up to first `</div>` of `<div id="subclass1">`
Could any help me to solve this?

Code I tried to capture is:

```
<div id="class1">(?:(?!<\/div>).)*?</div>
```

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML with regexes.  Regexes are not up to the task.  Use an HTML parser.  http://htmlparsing.com/perl.html has some examples for Perl.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348 - Read the answer to this question

Comment: Like most of the people said, there are a lot of HTML/XML modules in Perl, but if you want to feel like you built it, may be you will like **Parse::RecDescent**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a proper HTML parser.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $html = 'This is example <div id="class1">This is <div id="subclass1">This is </div> <div id="subclass2">This is </div> This is </div> This is example';

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_html_string($html);
my $root   = $doc->documentElement();

for my $div ($root->findnodes('//div[@id="class1"]')) {
   say "[", $div->toString(), "]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your source code. Is it possible this through regular expression

Comment: Sure, wrap the whole thing with `'' =~ /(?{ ... })/;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'This is example <div id="class1">This is <div id="subclass1">This is </div> <div id="subclass2">This is </div> This is </div> This is example' | sed -n 's/<div id="class1">\(.*\)<\/div>/\1/p'
This is example This is <div id="subclass1">This is </div> <div id="subclass2">This is </div> This is  This is example
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use appropriate HTML/XML parser.  If you want to do it with regex for any reason, nested regex helps you. (Check `perldoc perlre` for detail.)

```
$re = qr{
  (
    <div[^>]*>
    (?:(??{$re}) | [^<>]*)*
    </div>
  )
}x;

print "$1\n" if(/$re/o);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people always say "Use a proper HTML parser" to parse HTML and not regex.  What some people fail to realize is that there are requirements to be met and those requirements might require regex.

`<div id=".+?">.*</div>` should work for you.

http://regexr.com?33336